# Overidding imshow

Tags: image, matlab

When I use the following,

```
   imshow(imread('image1.jpg'));
   imshow(imread('image2.jpg'));
   imshow(imread('image3.jpg'));
   imshow(imread('image4.jpg'));
   imshow(imread('image5.jpg'));
   imshow(imread('image6.jpg'));
```

I got only image named image6.jpg in the output figure.

There is also an option **figure,imshow(...);** to view all the images each in new window.

But writing figure in each line where I need to view the image is a repeated and tedious process. Is there any other solution to get the same output as with **figure,imshow(..);** 
without using figure function.

I mainly put on this question because while programming a lot somewhere we forget to use the figure function and so the image that we need to view wont be visible. It would have been overwritten by other image. So provide me some solution.

I ask this only for simplicity in writing the code. So if there is any solution, please mention.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to write separate function that will contain "figure; imshow(input); end", and call it whenever you want to show an image with a new window, instead of just `"imshow"`

Comment: yah , that is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I don't think that there's a workaround to that. MATLAB basically changes the current figure handle to that of a new image when you use `imshow`. One thing you can do however is to make a copy of `imshow` in your local directory and edit it accordingly to make your own UDF.

What I would recommend however (so as to preserve functionality across systems) is that you open your code is an editor and replace all `imshow`s with `figure, imshow`. This should be easy enough and it'll be easy to revert back as well.